# I have a table that where the whole thing is the key (three elements) I am not sure its optimal?

Tags: database, database-design

Lets say I have the following tables:

Tasks Table:

```
Task ID, Task Name, Capability ID
```

Capabilities Table:

```
Capability ID, Capability Name
```

Applications Table:

```
App ID, App Name, App File
```

Components Table:

```
Component ID, Model, Manufacturer, Revision
```

Where:

- I want a task to have one associated capability.
- Each capability is made up of a set of specific components with a set of specific applications running on them.

So for example we have task1 which uses capability1. Capability1 requires:

- Component1 running {App1 and App2}
- Component2 running {App2}

So to resolve this I made a link table as follows:

Capability Parts:

```
Capability ID, Component ID, App ID
```

Where all three columns make the primary key. It feels like this needs to be split up further, but I can't see how to do that (or if it is required at all). I think I have satisfied database normal forms 1-3.

Is this correct (in terms of database normalisation) or is there some further optimisations I can make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you've got a many-to-many relationship between Capability, App, and Component.  Given that, the three-column link table you describe is perfectly reasonable, as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that - this is probably why I can't break it down further : )

Comment: Probably ;)  I tried to break it down into a pair of two-column link tables, but App is determined by both Capability and Component (based on your description), so while you COULD decompose them further, I think it would be more trouble than it's worth.  Trade-offs, trade-offs everywhere, and all of them make you think (with apologies to Sam Coleridge)

Comment: lol, yeah - I agree I don't think I want the hassle of breaking it up if it does not gain me anything : )